# Search for multiple column names in every table, and return table names

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a single query, for returning table names for every table in my database, that has 3 column names: `gps time, shape, id`.
I was looking for an answer, but everything works only for one column name.

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

When I add another `"AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name2'"` it returns 0.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('column_name', 'column_name2', 'column_name3')
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Is it possible, to sepparate the collection, and make something like multiple "AND" statements for this one ?

Comment: No, because `information_schema.COLUMNS` stores data like `table_name, column_name` means 3 rows for 3 columns. That is why I used `group by` to merge the rows at the end. You can check it by `select table_name, COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 ON c1.TABLE_NAME=c2.TABLE_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c3 ON c2.TABLE_NAME=c3.TABLE_NAME 
                                  AND c1.TABLE_NAME=c3.TABLE_NAME
WHERE c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'gps time'
  AND c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'shape'
  AND c3.COLUMN_NAME = 'id'
```